# Delete multiple Column(headers) in csv in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, algorithm, dataframe, csv

Here is my code

```
    import csv
#import pandas as pd

f = open("stu.csv", "a+", newline="")
Smain = csv.writer(f)
Smain.writerow(["Name", "Father Name", "Class", "Admission Number"])
mainrec = []
increas = 1

class1 = open("class-1.csv", "a+", newline="")
stuclas1 = csv.writer(class1)
stuclas1.writerow(["Roll Number", "Name", "Admission Number"])

while True:
    nam = input("Enter Student Name - ")
    Clas = int(input("Enter Class - "))
    Fname = input("Enter Father Name - ")
    adm = 100 + increas
    lst = [nam, Fname, Clas, adm]
    mainrec.append(lst)

    if Clas == 1:
        stucls1list = []
        a1 = 0
        rollnum_cla1 = 0 + increas + a1
        a1 = 0 + rollnum_cla1
        lst1 = [rollnum_cla1, nam, adm]
        stucls1list.append(lst1)
        for i1 in stucls1list:
            stuclas1.writerow(i1)
    increas += 1
    c = input("Input 'Y' If You Want To Record More, Otherwise Press 'N' - ")
    if c == "N":
        break
for i in mainrec:
    Smain.writerow(i)
# load dataset
#df = pd.read_csv("stu.csv")
# select the rows
# if Name column
# has special characters
#print(df[df.Name.str.contains(r'[Name]')])
# drop the merged selected rows

f.close()
class1.close()
```

Can anyone tell me how i can **delete duplicate header**
when i run this program more than 2 time it start duplication header and i dont want to duplicate header again and again please tell me how i can delete that header(column)

stu csv when
i run this program 2 times

```
Name,Father Name,Class,Admission Number
xyz,xyz,1,101
qwe,qwe,1,102
N,N,1,103
Name,Father Name,Class,Admission Number # this i want to delete
test,test,1,101
you,you,1,102
```

Comment: Don't create the problem in the first place.  Test whether the file is there and has the header before you decide to write the header.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to solve for it.

```
f = open("stu.csv", "a+", newline="")
f.seek(0)
if len(f.read()) == 0
    Smain = csv.writer(f)
    Smain.writerow(["Name", "Father Name", "Class", "Admission Number"])
```

This will check if there is content inside the file. If it has contents, then you already have the header. If there is no content, then you dont have a header. This will determine if you need to write the header to the file.

Here's the sample output when I tried:

First run:

```
No header   #my print statement output
```

Output file after first run: #the file header written to file

```
Name,Father Name,Class,Admission Number
```

Second run:

```
header found, skipped writing header again   #my print statement output
```

It did not write the output to file again.

Output file on second run:

```
Name,Father Name,Class,Admission Number
```

Note here that f.write will move the pointer to the last line by default (since the file is opened in `a+` mode)